# After DateTimeZone.convertLocalToUTC timezone still shows local

Tags: java, time, timezone, jodatime, timestamp-with-timezone

I use  DateTimeZone.convertLocalToUTC to convert local time to UTC. The time is changed correctly, but after conversion, the timezone info still says the Original local timezone. Please refer below sample code

```
Date gmttime = new Date(tz.convertLocalToUTC(System.currentTimeMillis(),false));
System.out.println(gmttime.toString());
```

Output :
Wed Oct 16 12:58:19 **IST** 2013

Please note the bold value, I expected it to be **UTC** . Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: FYI, `new Date` is depricated

Comment: then what is the alternative if new Date() is depricated ?

Comment: I mean `new Date(....)` is depricated .See my answer I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#Date.toString()` will print the date in the local timezone.

Use `SimpleDateFormat` to print the `Date` formatted for a specific `TimeZone`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM  dd HH:mm:ss:SS z");
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    System.out.println(format.format(date));
}
```

Comment: The time (HH:MM:SS) is displaying correctly in UTC, only the TimeZone prints as Local

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
final Date date = new Date();
final String ISO_FORMAT = "E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(ISO_FORMAT);
final TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
sdf.setTimeZone(utc);
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Output:

```
Wed Oct 16 08:53:50 UTC 2013
```

Answer (score 1):

`convertLocalToUTC` Converts a local instant to a standard UTC instant with the same local time. http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html